# Cant see the desktop except for the background Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: drivers, fglrx

This happened after I reinstalled the fglrx graphic drivers. Is this a problem with Unity or Compiz?

Comment: Try to run `unity --replace &` in your terminal, and see if anything happens. (AND - did you mess around with the CCSM ? )

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with Unity.

There's a bug tracker going on here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer-updates/+bug/1069199

I got back by right clicking the desktop -> change wallpaper then clicking "All Settings" in the top left, then "Software sources" bottom center, Additional drivers, the far right tab, then reset it to the default open source drivers.